# What's the correct way to add unlimited components to a form and be able to delete them and access its values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a web where you can add products to a database, the user must provide the product name, its price and then they can add unlimited attributes. Everytime the button "add attribute" ("añadir atributo al producto") is pressed, a ProductAttribute component is added to the form. This is managed by the "attributes" state. My problem is that, every time I press the delete icon, all components added after the one I press "delete" get deleted too. Also, I'm not sure how I will be able to access those values later.

Here's the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SlArrowLeft } from "react-icons/sl";
import { IoMdClose } from "react-icons/io";

const CreateProduct = () => {
    const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([]);

    const addAttribute = () => {
        setAttributes([
            ...attributes,
            <ProductAttribute
                key={attributes.length}
                position={attributes.length}
                attributes={attributes}
                setAttributes={setAttributes}
            />,
        ]);
    };

    return (
        <div className="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-2 py-3">
            <h1 className="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 py-2 md:text-2xl flex items-center">
                <Link to={"/gestionar-productos"} className="mr-4">
                    <SlArrowLeft />
                </Link>
                Crear nuevo producto
            </h1>

            <form action="#">
                <div className="grid gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-6">
                    <div className="w-full">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="name"
                            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                        >
                            Nombre del producto
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            id="name"
                            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
                            placeholder="Escribe el nombre del producto"
                            required=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-full">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="price"
                            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                        >
                            Precio
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            name="price"
                            id="price"
                            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
                            placeholder="$1000"
                            required=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    {attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>{attribute}</div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button
                    className="inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-4 sm:mt-6 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-primary-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-primary-900 hover:bg-primary-800"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={addAttribute}
                >
                    Añadir atributo al producto
                </button>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="w-full text-white bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-500 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mt-6"
                >
                    Crear producto
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

const ProductAttribute = ({ position, attributes, setAttributes }) => {
    const deleteAttribute = () => {
        const updatedAttributes = attributes.filter(
            (_, index) => index !== position
        );
        setAttributes(updatedAttributes);
    };

    return (
        <div className="py-5 px-5 border rounded-lg relative">
            <button
                onClick={deleteAttribute}
                className="py-2 absolute top-1 right-4"
            >
                <IoMdClose size={20} color="red" />
            </button>
            <div className="w-full">
                <label
                    htmlFor="atribute"
                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                >
                    Atributo del producto
                </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="atribute"
                    id="atribute"
                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
                    placeholder="Escribe el atributo del producto"
                    required=""
                />
            </div>
            <div className="w-full mt-2">
                <label
                    htmlFor="quantity"
                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                >
                    Cantidad
                </label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="quantity"
                    id="quantity"
                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
                    placeholder="10"
                    required="Escribe la cantidad del atributo"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CreateProduct;
```

I tried deleting on the array using its key but I couldn't, I also tried adding an id prop to the component to see if I could delete the component using that, but I just got the same result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Diagnosis

The behavior you are seeing is due to the way you have the `addAttribute()` set up:

```
const addAttribute = () => {
  setAttributes([
    ...attributes,
    <ProductAttribute
      key={attributes.length}
      position={attributes.length}
      attributes={attributes}
      setAttributes={setAttributes}
    />,
  ]);
};
```

The value of `attributes` passed to the `<ProductAttribute>` will always be the value of `attributes` before the new `<ProductAttribute>` is added:

- `<ProductAttribute key={1}>`: `attributes = []`
- `<ProductAttribute key={2}>`: `attributes = [<ProductAttribute key={1}>]`
- `<ProductAttribute key={3}>`: `attributes = [<ProductAttribute key={1}>, <ProductAttribute key={2}>]`

Thus, when the `deleteAttribute()` function is called within the `<ProductAttribute>` component, it will delete all `<ProductAttribute>` components before it. For example, for `<ProductAttribute key={1}>`:

```js
const deleteAttribute = () => {
  // attributes = []
  const updatedAttributes = attributes.filter(
    (_, index) => index !== position
  );
  // attributes = []
  setAttributes(updatedAttributes);
};
```

### Solution

Instead, consider managing the state entirely in the parent `<CreateProduct>` component.

#### Adding new entries

Have the `attributes` state be a collection of plain objects (it is uncommon to have state with React components within them):

```js
const addAttribute = () => {
  setAttributes((values) => values.concat({ id: Date.now() }));
};
```

We pass a function to `setAttributes()`. We use a function so that it is passed the most up-to-date state value. This prevents any possibility of stale values.

We append a plain object with a unique `id` that we generate from the current timestamp for simplicity's sake in this answer. We use a plain object since we can add properties as needed by the child `<ProductAttribute>` components later on.

#### Render `<ProductAttribute>`

We render the `<ProductAttribute>` components from the `attributes` state:

```
{attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
  <ProductAttribute
    key={attribute.id}
    position={index}
    attribute={attribute}
  />
))}
```

#### Implement deletion

Have a function in `<CreateProduct>` that deletes the attribute for the `attributes` state. We do this by having a higher-order function with the `id` parameter, which then returns another function that should be called when said attribute with the passed `id` should be deleted:

```
const deleteAttribute = (id) => () => {
  setAttributes((values) => values.filter(({ id: findId }) => findId !== id));
};

// …

{attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
  <ProductAttribute
    …
    onDelete={deleteAttribute(attribute.id)}
  />
))}

// …

const ProductAttribute = ({ position, attribute, onDelete }) => {
  // …
  <button onClick={onDelete} …>
```

#### Updating attributes individually

With the aforementioned state management, you can update attributes individually by using a higher-order function similar to `onDelete()`:

```
const updateAttribute = (index) => (newAttribute) => {
  setAttributes((values) => [
    ...values.slice(0, index),
    newAttribute,
    ...values.slice(index + 1),
  ]);
};

// …

{attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
  <ProductAttribute
    …
    onUpdate={updateAttribute(index)}
  />
))}

// …

const ProductAttribute = ({ …, onUpdate }) => {
```

`<ProductAttribute>` should call the `onUpdate()` function prop whenever the attribute it manages should be updated. In this example, it must ensure the full state object entry in full to ensure a correct update. Of course, you can modify this behavior to suit your own needs.

### Working example

```js
const { useState } = React;
const Link = ({ ...props, children }) => <a {...props}>{children}</a>;
const SlArrowLeft = () => (
  <svg
    stroke="currentColor"
    fill="currentColor"
    stroke-width="0"
    viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
    height="1em"
    width="1em"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path d="M752.145 0c8.685 0 17.572 3.434 24.237 10.099 13.33 13.33 13.33 35.143 0 48.473L320.126 515.03l449.591 449.591c13.33 13.33 13.33 35.144 0 48.474-13.33 13.33-35.142 13.33-48.472 0L247.418 539.268c-13.33-13.33-13.33-35.144 0-48.474L727.91 10.1C734.575 3.435 743.46.002 752.146.002z"></path>
  </svg>
);
const IoMdClose = ({ size = "1em", color = "" }) => (
  <svg
    stroke="currentColor"
    fill="currentColor"
    stroke-width="0"
    viewBox="0 0 512 512"
    height="1em"
    width="1em"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    style={{ color }}
  >
    <path d="M405 136.798L375.202 107 256 226.202 136.798 107 107 136.798 226.202 256 107 375.202 136.798 405 256 285.798 375.202 405 405 375.202 285.798 256z"></path>
  </svg>
);

const CreateProduct = () => {
  const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([]);

  const addAttribute = () => {
    setAttributes((values) => values.concat({ id: Date.now() }));
  };

  const updateAttribute = (index) => (newAttribute) => {
    setAttributes((values) => [
      ...values.slice(0, index),
      newAttribute,
      ...values.slice(index + 1),
    ]);
  };

  const deleteAttribute = (id) => () => {
    setAttributes((values) => values.filter(({ id: findId }) => findId !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-2 py-3">
      <h1 className="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 py-2 md:text-2xl flex items-center">
        <Link to={"/gestionar-productos"} className="mr-4">
          <SlArrowLeft />
        </Link>
        Crear nuevo producto
      </h1>

      <form action="#">
        <div className="grid gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-6">
          <div className="w-full">
            <label
              htmlFor="name"
              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
            >
              Nombre del producto
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
              placeholder="Escribe el nombre del producto"
              required=""
            />
          </div>
          <div className="w-full">
            <label
              htmlFor="price"
              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
            >
              Precio
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="price"
              id="price"
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
              placeholder="$1000"
              required=""
            />
          </div>
          {attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
            <ProductAttribute
              key={attribute.id}
              position={index}
              attribute={attribute}
              onUpdate={updateAttribute(index)}
              onDelete={deleteAttribute(attribute.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <button
          className="inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-4 sm:mt-6 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-primary-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-primary-900 hover:bg-primary-800"
          type="button"
          onClick={addAttribute}
        >
          Añadir atributo al producto
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full text-white bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-500 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mt-6"
        >
          Crear producto
        </button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(attributes)}>
        Log attributes state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const ProductAttribute = ({ position, attribute, onUpdate, onDelete }) => {
  const updateName = ({ target }) => {
    onUpdate({
      ...attribute,
      name: target.value,
    });
  };
  
  const updateQuantity = ({ target }) => {
    onUpdate({
      ...attribute,
      quantity: parseInt(target.value, 10),
    });
  };
 
  return (
    <div className="py-5 px-5 border rounded-lg relative">
      <button onClick={onDelete} className="py-2 absolute top-1 right-4">
        <IoMdClose size={20} color="red" />
      </button>
      <div className="w-full">
        <label
          htmlFor="atribute"
          className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
        >
          Atributo del producto
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="atribute"
          id="atribute"
          className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
          placeholder="Escribe el atributo del producto"
          required=""
          value={attribute.name || ''}
          onInput={updateName}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="w-full mt-2">
        <label
          htmlFor="quantity"
          className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
        >
          Cantidad
        </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="quantity"
          id="quantity"
          className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5"
          placeholder="10"
          required="Escribe la cantidad del atributo"
          value={parseInt(attribute.quantity || 0, 10)}
          onInput={updateQuantity}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<CreateProduct />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```